# Extract jpg property 'keyword' from terminal

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, images, file-metadata

Using Ubuntu 20.04, I can right-click on a jpg and select 'properties'. A window will open containing the tab 'image'. In this tab, there is a section called 'Keywords', the content of which I would like to receive from the terminal. I tried `identify -verbose example.jpg`, `exif example.jpg`, `file example.jpg`, but none of these approaches delivered the Keyword. Does anybody know how I could achieve this?

The goal of this is to create a folder for each keyword (if not existing already) and put each jpg in the respective folder. I want to write this in a shell script, which I will initiate using a personal command. Any suggestions on how to write this script are also more than welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Edit 8 Feb 21:
Following this [thread](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=16450&sid=b1e1c43180899fe37f938aa8f8d091f8&start=15), I converted the the jpg to xmp. The metadata is available in the xmp. How can I read it out easily?

Comment: I just tried with `identify -verbose` and it showed the keywords.

Comment: Once again, I read the output carefully and tried to grep, but did not succeed. ```identify --version``` outputs ```Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-7 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-20 https://imagemagick.org```. Which version do you use?

Comment: My version `ImageMagick 6.9.10-23`.

Comment: Could you show the `grep` command? The visual inspection may not be reliable.

Comment: ```identify -version example.jpg | grep my_keyword```

Comment: Use `grep Keyword`.

Comment: ```my_keyword``` represents the keyword I'm looking for. However, ```Keyword``` doesn't work. I suppose ```ìdentify -verbose``` doesn't output the keyword for some reason. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this option, using the `exiv2` tool:

```
sudo apt install exiv2
```

Then we can print the XMP data like this:

```bsh
$ exiv2 -P X image.jpg
Xmp.iptc.Keywords        XmpBag      1      Some tag
```

Answer (score -1):

[Hachoir metadata](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/hachoir-metadata) is a nice program to handle this kind of usecases

Installation

```
sudo apt-get install python-hachoir-metadata
```

Usage

```
hachoir-metadata example.jpg
```

Sample output

```
Metadata:
- Image width: 192 pixels
- Image height: 192 pixels
- Bits/pixel: 32
- Pixel format: RGBA
- Compression rate: 11.3x
- Creation date: 2020-08-10 22:57:38
- Compression: deflate
- Comment: date:create=2020-08-10T22:57:38+02:00
- Comment: date:modify=2020-08-10T22:57:38+02:00
- MIME type: image/png
- Endianness: Big endian
```

See [the online documentation](https://hachoir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metadata.html) for more info.

Comment: Would you mind also showing how to use that tool to actually solve the given issue? Without that info, this is clearly just a "link-only" answer.

Comment: Informations added!